# Discord BOT python, How to send message when specific user wrote the command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i want to make my Discord BOT do something like this :

If i say 'react' the BOT will respond

If someone else than me says 'react' the BOT will not respond

I've tried this code bellow but it don't work for me

`if message.author.id == ('<User ID here>') and message.content.lower() == 'react':`

`await message.channel.send('i am only react to my Master not others!')`

Maybe i wrote something wrong in the code? please tell me it'll help me a lot!

Comment: Please list the full function. There is not enough information here to see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

That should do exactly what you want:

```
@client.event
#We create an on message event
async def on_message(message):
     #We check if the the message that has been sent equals react
     if "react" in message.content:
          #We check that the person who sent the message is you
          if type(message.author) == discord.user.ClientUser:
             #Do something
          else:
             #Do something else
     else:
          pass
```

Comment: just use the part of the message.author and integrate it in your code and ut should work

Comment: are you using discord.py rewrite?

Comment: I tried this code ```if message.author.id == <my ID here> and message.content.lower() == 'react' : await message.channel.send('reacted!')``` and it does nothing when i write 'react'

Comment: Try my edited code, i changed it to ```if "react" in message.content:```

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake *i guess* so i did write like this before

```
if message.author.id == ('<User ID here>') and message.content.lower() == 'react':

    await message.channel.send('i am only react to my Master not others!')
```

I should not put (brackets) after `message.author.id` and this is the correct one

```
if message.author.id == <ID goes here> and message.content.lower() == 'react':
    await message.channel.send('reacted!')
```